# Knapp, Lie Groups: beyond an Introduction, Theorem II.2.15

Tags: proof-explanation, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am studying Cartan subalgebras using Knapp's book, *Lie Groups: beyond an Introduction*.

I have difficulty understanding a few minor points in the proof of Theorem II.2.15, which states that

[image]

In his proof, he proved 6 other results to show that the theorem is true.
[image]

I understand the proofs of all of them, **besides part (c)** (highlighted). Here is the definition of $\mathfrak{g}_{0, Y}$:
[image]

**Here are the statements I do not understand:**

1.

> Since $R_{\mathfrak{h}}(\mathfrak{g})$ is open in $\mathfrak{h}$, the tangent space at $Y$ may be regarded as $\mathfrak{h}$ (with $c_H(t) = Y + tH$ being a curve with derivative $H \in \mathfrak{h})$

Question: Why is $R_{\mathfrak{h}}(\mathfrak{g})$ is open in $\mathfrak{h}$, and why $c_H(t) = Y + tH$ and $R_{\mathfrak{h}}(\mathfrak{g})$ being open imply that the tangent space at $Y$ may be regarded as $\mathfrak{h}$?

2.

> $R_{\mathfrak{g}}(\mathfrak{g})$ is dense.

Question: Why is $R_{\mathfrak{g}}(\mathfrak{g})$ dense?

For reference, I have also included the whole proof in the screenshot below:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given part (a) $R_\mathfrak{h}(\mathfrak{g})$ is the complement of a finite union of hyperplanes in $\mathfrak{h}$ which makes it open (as well as dense in $R_\mathfrak{h}(\mathfrak{g})$).

The fact that the tangent space at $Y$ is $\mathfrak{h}$ is just a fact about such a submanifold of a vector space. You can probably find this as an example in any introduction to Algebraic Geometry (although you'll need to translate the definition of tangent space) but he demonstrates it here by showing an example curve which has derivative $H$ for all $H\in \mathfrak{h}$.

The fact that $R_\mathfrak{g}(\mathfrak{g})$ (which I assume is defined as the set of regular semisimple elements in $\mathfrak{g}$) is dense in $\mathfrak{g}$, I suspect will be proved or mentioned earlier by Knapp.

Comment: The only earlier mention about dense is that the set of $Z \in \mathfrak{g}_{0, X}$ such that $ad W|_{\mathfrak{g} / \mathfrak{g}_{0, X}}$ is nonsingular (which is the set where some polynomial is nonvanishing), is dense. Not sure if this is related to what we're working on.

Comment: Thanks, I understand part (a) now. I haven't learned algebraic geometry yet, so I guess I'll try to reason it myself. My logic is that since $R_\mathfrak{h}(\mathfrak{g})$ is an open submanifold, it has a codimension of 0, and by taking derivative on curves $c_H(t)$, we know we have tangent vectors $H \in \mathfrak{h}$ in the tangent space at $Y$, and since $dim \mathfrak{h} = dim T_Y R_\mathfrak{h}(\mathfrak{g})$, $H \in \mathfrak{h}$ spans $T_Y R_\mathfrak{h}(\mathfrak{g})$?

Comment: @mlcv2022 You don't have to get too into algebraic geometry for that. I just think it is an example situation that probably gets discussed there. In more differential geometry terms a codimension 0 submanifold is always going to have tangent space equal to the tangent space of the ambient space and the tangent spaces in a vector space are all equal to the whole vector space.

Comment: Thanks. I think I’ll let go of the dense argument for now and accept the answer.